# How is it possible to join dock to railway station?

Tags: openttd

It seems openttd does not allowed to join dock to railway station, only in separated way. Unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you can't join a dock to a railway station? I've just built a railway station and placed a dock on an adjacent tile without issue. See http://i.imgur.com/LEjHX8w.png

Comment: To add to what KingJ said, the different stations **need** to be adjacent orthogonally (connecting the sides, not the corners) in order for them to be considered the same entity. Can you tell more about your situation, maybe adding a screenshot and mentioning the OpenTTD version?

Comment: Hey, I figured out, the biggest distance between all the joined station should be lower then 12, and I had other bus stations too. These violated to place harbour, but the I placed dock on the other side of the station. So it works now.

Comment: You'll normally receive the "Station Too Spread Out" error in that case. To increase the maximun spread, go in to Advanced Options, expand Stations and adjust the "Max station spread" setting. The default value is 12, higher values will cause a performance hit. I normally increase it as required, 20 is the highest i've ever needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you build a station of one type (eg. dock) next to a station of a different type (eg. rail) the game will automatically join the two, provided that the combined station does not exceed the maximum permitted station size.

From version 0.7.0 onwards, if distant joining of stations is enabled in the advanced settings, you can hold down the `control` key while placing a station near another station: the game will give you the option to combine the two stations if the resulting station will not exceed the maximum station size.

In both cases, the combined station will share a common pool of cargo and have a single approval rating for each cargo type, but will count as two (or more) stations for the purposes of the company performance rating score.